# Slideup sublist when one sublist is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want that when I click on a sublist, the other automatically slides up if it was opened before. I tried using .siblings with no luck. This is my code and markup:

```
    /* Shop Filter */
    function shopfilter(that) {
        $(that).toggleClass('active');
        $(that).next('.color:first').slideToggle();
    }

                <ul id="filter_box">
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="shopfilter(this);">COLOR</a>
                        <ul class="color">
                            <li>
                                <img src="img/color1.png" alt="color1" width="14" height="15">
                                <span>Color 1</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="img/color2.png" alt="color1" width="14" height="15">
                                <span>Color 2</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="shopfilter(this);">PRECIO</a>
                        <ul class="color">
                            <li>
                                <span>>50</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>100</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="shopfilter(this);">TALLA</a>
                        <ul class="color">
                            <li>
                                <span>XS</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>S</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve it?

**Edit**: The toggleClass('active') is just used to change the direction of the arrow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.
I changed slideToggle to slideUp/Down to be sure it's in sync with the active class.

```
function shopfilter(that) {
    $('.active').slideUp();
    if ($(that).hasClass('active')) {
        $(that).slideUp().removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(that).slideDown().addClass('active');
    }
}
```

I've made a fiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/dnvaL/

Comment: Check the fiddle I've just made.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar thought to Sylvanus (re: using `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`), but with a slightly different approach, where you reset all menus, before opening the new one.

```
function shopfilter(that) {
    //check to see if the current menu is already open
    var isOpen = ($(that).hasClass('active')) ? true : false;

    //reset the menus
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.color').slideUp();

    // display the selected menu if it was closed
    if (!(isOpen)) {
        $(that).addClass('active');
        $(that).next('.color:first').slideDown();
    }
}
```

Menus that are already closed will not be affected, but any that are currently open will be close. The `isOpen` check makes sure that you don't reopen a menu when you click on it again to to close it.

Comment: this would be the best solution, nice!